# Customize Spacy NER using IOB tagging scheme for Movie Review dataset

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I have previously used CRF++ model to identify NER in movie review dataset. However, I have found spacy very effective in usage and visualization. However, the question here is that how I can incorporate CRF++ model in spacy? If this is not possible how can I train Spacy NER model for my requirement using IOB tagging?

Answer (score 0):

The spaCy model is based on a custom designed CNN model, that best decried [here](https://spacy.io/api/#section-nn-model). So, it doesn't have an internal CRF model, but using the custom pipeline you can use you custom CRF model with spaCy, check [this](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) for details.

To train NER model using spaCy you data must be in [BILUO format](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#biluo), so you should first convert your data then follow [the excellent doc about it](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner).
There is also a converter for it:

```
python -m spacy convert [input_file] [output_dir] [--converter] [--n-sents]
[--morphology]
```

which can be used to convert the data with `conll` and `ion` to spaCy format.